# Why does this code work with my array, but not when I typed in an array of strings? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, undefined

This code works when I have my array of arrays of numbers, but not when I typed in an array of arrays of strings; I did change the code to use .length afterward for the strings, but that helps. The error is with the line of "arr[i].reduce(function (onea, twoa) {" being an undefined function in the second version.
Oh, @user1600124, that prompt might be the error, even though I did still type in "[ ["one", "two", "three"], ["one1", "two2", "three3"] ]", it changed that all into a string. You have solved it, I think, but is there a way for user input without prompt. Thanks, @user1600124 for your solution!

```
var ArrayWidth = function(arr){
  var ret = [], i; 
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   
    arr[i].reduce(function (onea, twoa) {
      return ret[i] = Math.max(onea.length, twoa.length); //added ".length" to stings version
    }, 0); //added ",0" to strings version
  ret[i] = ret[i].toString().length;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Working full code of array of arrays of numbers:

```
//Draws Non=Jagged Table with columns be the arrays in the array of arrays and the first being the heading.
var arrays = [
    [111111, 22222, 333],
    [444444444, 534334, 63],
    [73, 83748395, 9343],
    [279571, 327894598571490581, 34815, 2]
];

function ArrayHeight (arr) {
  var ret = [], i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    window["a"+i] = arr[i];
    ret[i] = window["a"+i];
    for(j = 0; j < ret[i].length; j++)
          ret[i][j] = ret[i][j].toString();
  }
  return ret;
}
var ArrayWidth = function(arr){
  var ret = [], i; 
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   
    arr[i].reduce(function (onea, twoa) {
      return ret[i] = Math.max(onea, twoa);
    });
  ret[i] = ret[i].toString().length;
  }
  return ret;
}
function addSpace (){
  var ret = ArrayHeight(arrays);
  console.log(ret);
  var widthOfRet = ArrayWidth(arrays);
  console.log(widthOfRet);
  var i, j, k;
  for(j = 0; j < ret.length; j++){
    for(k = 0; k < (ret[j].length); k++){
      for(i = ret[j][k].length; i < (widthOfRet[j] + 1); i++){
        ret[j][k] = ret[j][k] + " ";
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

var drawTable = function(){
  var ret = addSpace();
  var ArrayWid = ArrayWidth(arrays);
  var table = "", retFirst = "", retSecond = "", totaled = 0, i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < ArrayWid.length; i++)
    totaled = totaled + ArrayWid[i];
  for(i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
    retFirst = retFirst + ret[i][0];
  for(i = 0; i < (totaled + ret.length); i++)
    retSecond = retSecond + "-";
  for(j = 0; j < ret.length; j++)
    for(i = 0; i < ret[j].length; i++)
      window["reti"+i] = "";
  for(j = 0; j < ret.length; j++)
    for(i = 0; i < ret[j].length; i++)
      window["reti"+i] = window["reti"+i] + ret[j][i];
  table = retFirst + "\n" + retSecond;
  for(i = 1; window["reti"+i] != undefined; i++)
    table = table + "\n" + window["reti"+i];
  return table;
}
console.log(drawTable());
```

nonworking with array of arrays of strings:

```
//Draws Non-Jagged Table with columns be the arrays in the array of arrays and the first being the heading.
var arrays = prompt("To draw a table, type in an array of arrays. Each array is a column and the first is the heading. Cannot be jagged.", "[ [ , ... ], [, ... ], ... ]");

function ArrayHeight (arr) {
  var ret = [], i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    window["a"+i] = arr[i];
    ret[i] = window["a"+i];
    for(j = 0; j < ret[i].length; j++)
          ret[i][j] = ret[i][j].toString();
  }
  return ret;
}
var ArrayWidth = function(arr){
  var ret = [], i; 
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   
    arr[i].reduce(function (onea, twoa) {
      return ret[i] = Math.max(onea.length, twoa.length);
    }, 0);
  ret[i] = ret[i].toString().length;
  }
  return ret;
}
function addSpace (){
  var ret = ArrayHeight(arrays);
  console.log(ret);
  var widthOfRet = ArrayWidth(arrays);
  console.log(widthOfRet);
  var i, j, k;
  for(j = 0; j < ret.length; j++){
    for(k = 0; k < (ret[j].length); k++){
      for(i = ret[j][k].length; i < (widthOfRet[j] + 1); i++){
        ret[j][k] = ret[j][k] + " ";
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

var drawTable = function(){
  var ret = addSpace();
  var ArrayWid = ArrayWidth(arrays);
  var table = "", retFirst = "", retSecond = "", totaled = 0, i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < ArrayWid.length; i++)
    totaled = totaled + ArrayWid[i];
  for(i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
    retFirst = retFirst + ret[i][0];
  for(i = 0; i < (totaled + ret.length); i++)
    retSecond = retSecond + "-";
  for(j = 0; j < ret.length; j++)
    for(i = 0; i < ret[j].length; i++)
      window["reti"+i] = "";
  for(j = 0; j < ret.length; j++)
    for(i = 0; i < ret[j].length; i++)
      window["reti"+i] = window["reti"+i] + ret[j][i];
  table = retFirst + "\n" + retSecond;
  for(i = 1; window["reti"+i] != undefined; i++)
    table = table + "\n" + window["reti"+i];
  return table;
}
console.log(drawTable());
alert("Your table is in the console.log");
```

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script language="javascript">

//script was here

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: What Browser are you using?

Comment: What may I ask, are you trying to do? `reduce` by in itself does nothing. I don't see you assigning the reduced value anywhere in your code.

Comment: The browser was Google Chrome, but it was the same thing in a code sandbox opened in chrome. Thanks, @PHPglue

Comment: @JibiAbraham, In this situation, reduce is finding the maximum string length of the indexes of an array. Thanks!

Comment: It is actually an array of arrays of stings, @cookiemonster; sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The `undefined` is because a `Number` does not have a length property on it

Comment: @cookiemonster, I would be reducing an array of arrays of strings like: [ ["one", "two", "three"], ["one1", "two2", "three3"] ]

Comment: You may want to give everyone a sample input+expected output

Comment: @JibiAbraham, the .length was added after the only array of arrays of numbers, and was not with the array of arrays of number, but thanks!

Comment: I will post the full code of both the original and the strings as the example. The full code has been added!

Comment: Why even use `.reduce()` when you're not assigning it to anything?

Comment: @PHPglue, reduce is being used to find the maximum of the lengths of the strings, but thanks for the comment!

Comment: Oh, @user1600124, that prompt might be the error, even though I did still type in "[ ["one", "two", "three"], ["one1", "two2", "three3"] ]", it changed that all into a string. You have solved it, I think, but is there a way for user input without prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the reduce function on the content of the input array.
When you have array of arrays of numbers, arr[i] is an array, and hence has the reduce method

When you have array of strings, arr[i] is a string, and do not have the reduce method you tried to use. So you end up with errors

Comment: Well, with the array of arrays of strings, I was using the reduce function with the strings `.length` as seen with the `Math.max(onea.length, twoa.length);` But, Thanks @user1600124! :)

Comment: it doesn't matter if you used onea.length or onea itself as the value you are using.. your code never reached that point. The arr[i].reduce() function call would emit error as the reduce function does not exist for your arr[i]...

Comment: Well @user1600124, it did work with out the .length for the array of numbers. adding .length would make a number value for the strings, and therefore should work. Thanks!

Comment: Your function accept an array (arr), loop through the array (arr[i]), and call arr[i].reduce(). When the input is an array of strings, arr[i] is a string, it does not have a reduce function. So your code stops there. It never reached the onea.length, twoa.length part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function ArrayWidth(ary){
  var r = [];
  for(var i=0,l=ary.length; i<l; i++) {   
    r[i] = ary[i].reduce(function(a, b){
      return Math.max(a, b);
    }, 0);
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `for-in` on an Array in JavaScript. It's really much better to use `for`.

Comment: @PHPglue, it also gave me a type error on     "r[i] = ary[i].reduce(function(a, b){" saying that it was an undefined function. I also had to change arr to ary on that same line otherwise it said that arr was not defined.

Comment: Note that `ary` would have to be a multidimensional Array for the code to work.

Comment: @PHPglue: It doesn't have anything to do with old browsers and the DOM. There are several issues. Order of iteration is not guaranteed (not a problem here, but is in other cases). It's slower. You'll encounter additions/patches to `Array.prototype` during the enumeration. It simply offers no advantage, but comes with several disadvantages.

Comment: That's a lot of negatives to save a few characters. Hard to take that too seriously.